# Transfer session between computers

Tags: ssh, users

At my uni, we use ubuntu on our lab machines, and we can log in anywhere on the network, and ssh into any lab machine. Is it possible to be logged into one machine then decide to transfer the current session to another machine?

I've heard of reptyr, but I don't know if that's anything to do with this. (it seems like moving process between sessions on the same machine)

(the use case being if you are sitting in a row of computers and would like to move along to make space for a group of people).

Comment: You mean like tmux or screen? https://tmux.github.io/

Comment: I don't think they work between different computers?

Comment: you could ssh back in to your previous workstation and re-connect to your screen or tmux session.   you will be sharing CPU & RAM and other resources with the new user at that workstation, though.  and this is only good for shells and text mode apps, including ncurses apps.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by 'between different computers'. 

With `tmux` / `screen` / `VNC` / whatever you can 'decouple / disconnect' your session and append it to another terminal. Your processes continue run while de-coupled, and you can resume your terminal session as you log in from a different system over SSH. 

And yes, you can use repyr to re-parent processes not started in `tmux` - to tmux, detach - then SSH into your system from another terminal - and re-attach tmux. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Different computers, as in a physically separate box on the network, with it's own seperate display screen. Like say there is a row of 5 unused computers, and I come and use the middle one. Then then 3 people come along wanting to work in a group next to each other. Can I move to the next computer without logging off and logging back on and reopening everything I had open.

Comment: The computers run Ubuntu, and if I do `tmux ls` then it says "failed to connect to server"

Comment: I have done it before, with different computers and even with the original session on a computer connected to from an iPod. tmux will definitely do it if you do it correctly.